# How can I download an image, not shown in the URL, via Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, url, download

I'm trying so hard at discovering Node. Now I just found out about deathbycaptcha.js . So I wanted to test it on pretty lame captchas of an E-Mail provider. (GMX) And I've experienced something, that I've never seen before. The Url has no .jpg in it and is still interpreted as .jpg by my browser, without any code input. (At least as far as I can see.)

However if I try to download it via the Node Downloader, it does nor grab the image file, but something, that neither code or image.

I honestly have no clue, what I am actually facing, but I would really appreciate learning about it. Could you please help me out?

The image I'm talking about: <strike>[<strike>here</strike>](https://registrierung.gmx.net/?1-IResourceListener-bodyContainer-brand~container~border-brand~container~border_body-signup~form-form-captchaPanel-captcha~image-captcha~image&antiCache=1461483820234)</strike>

*edit:* The image appears to be expiring after some time. Just go to the registration page and grab your own one as explained below.

If you couldn't load it. That would be one clue already, but you should be able to do so, because I tried it with my mobile aswell.

However if it doesnt work, go to the sign-up page and check out the Captcha link: [here](https://registrierung.gmx.net/#.mail.hero_1.1.registrierung)

Additional info: If I would find out how to grab it, it wouldn't be a problem for me to do it from the same session. So (I guess) acces is no problem...

Comment: Your first link shows a GMX registration page for me. (iPad Pro)

Comment: Thank you. :) - Added information.